# Changing color a of 5 rectangles gradually using a seek bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-seekbar

I have 5 rectangles on my screen and a seek bar in the bottom (see the image link below). I am trying to change the color of the 4 out of 5 rectangles (except the gray one int middle right) gradually by moving the seek bar. I used drawRect method in RectAngle class to draw the 5 rectangles, but I instantiated them in a different class (GloblaUIVariables class) to make them global, but nothing happens when I move the seek bar to the right. What am I doing wring here. Thanks for your help.

[Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nm0q.png)

Here is my RectAngle class:

```
 public class RectAngle extends View {

        public RectAngle(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
        public RectAngle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public RectAngle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            float x = getWidth();
            float y = getHeight();



            // Draw  the top left rectangle
            GlobalUIVariables.topLeftRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            GlobalUIVariables.topLeftRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#66FFFF"));
           // canvas.drawPaint(topLeftRect);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, x / 2, y / 2, GlobalUIVariables.topLeftRect);


            //Draw the bottom left rectangle

            GlobalUIVariables.bottomLeftRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            //bottomLeftRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
           // canvas.drawPaint(bottomLeftRect);
            GlobalUIVariables.bottomLeftRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
            canvas.drawRect(0, y / 2, x / 2, y, GlobalUIVariables.bottomLeftRect);

            //Draw the top tight rectangle

            GlobalUIVariables.topRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            //topRightRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            GlobalUIVariables.topRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6600"));
            //canvas.drawPaint(topRightRect);
            canvas.drawRect(x / 2, 0, x, y / 3, GlobalUIVariables.topRightRect);

            // Draw the middle right rectangle

            GlobalUIVariables.midRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            GlobalUIVariables.midRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
           // canvas.drawPaint(midRightRect);
            canvas.drawRect(x / 2, y/3, x, 2*y / 3, GlobalUIVariables.midRightRect);

            //Draw the bottom right rectangle

            GlobalUIVariables.bottomRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            //bottomRightRect.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            GlobalUIVariables.bottomRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCC00"));
           // canvas.drawPaint(bottomRightRect);
            canvas.drawRect(x/2, 2*y/3, x, y, GlobalUIVariables.bottomRightRect);




        }
    }
```

Here is my main activity class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(new RectAngle(this));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SeekBar seekBar;
        RectAngle rect;

        seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                RectAngle rect;
                rect = (RectAngle)findViewById(R.id.rectangle);
                rect.postInvalidate();
                GlobalUIVariables.topLeftRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                GlobalUIVariables.topLeftRect.setColor(Color.rgb(23 - progress, 200 + progress, 99 + progress));
                GlobalUIVariables.bottomLeftRect.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 133 + progress, 144 - progress));
                GlobalUIVariables.topRightRect.setColor((Color.rgb(88 + progress, 200 - progress, 177 + progress)));
                GlobalUIVariables.bottomRightRect.setColor(Color.rgb(230, 56 + progress, 233 - progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my GlobalUIVariables class:

```
public class GlobalUIVariables extends Application {
    public static Paint topLeftRect = new Paint();
    public static Paint bottomLeftRect = new Paint();
    public static Paint topRightRect = new Paint();
    public static Paint midRightRect = new Paint();
    public static Paint bottomRightRect = new Paint();
}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.example.hassan.modernartui.RectAngle
        android:id="@+id/rectangle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:max="100"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the paints from the beginning (when the view is created).  That way we can also get rid of using the application class, GlobalUIVariables, usages. Heres how you can put this data in the view and step 2 will show you how to change them:

1. Put the paints in the RectAngle class

   ```
   public class RectAngle extends View {

       public Paint topLeftRect, bottomLeftRect, topRightRect, midRightRect, bottomRightRect;

       public RectAngle(Context context) {
           super(context);
           initPaints();
       }
       public RectAngle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           this(context, attrs, 0);
       }

       public RectAngle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
           initPaints();
       }

       void initPaints(){
           topLeftRect = new Paint();
           bottomLeftRect = new Paint();
           topRightRect = new Paint();
           midRightRect = new Paint();
           bottomRightRect = new Paint();
           topLeftRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
           topLeftRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#66FFFF"));
           bottomLeftRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
           bottomLeftRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
           topRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
           topRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6600"));
           midRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
           midRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
           bottomRightRect.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
           bottomRightRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCC00"));
       }
       @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           super.onDraw(canvas);

           float x = getWidth();
           float y = getHeight();
           // Draw  the top left rectangle
           canvas.drawRect(0, 0, x / 2, y / 2, topLeftRect);

           //Draw the bottom left rectangle
           canvas.drawRect(0, y / 2, x / 2, y, bottomLeftRect);

           //Draw the top tight rectangle
           canvas.drawRect(x / 2, 0, x, y / 3, topRightRect);

           // Draw the middle right rectangle
           canvas.drawRect(x / 2, y/3, x, 2*y / 3, midRightRect);

           //Draw the bottom right rectangle
           canvas.drawRect(x/2, 2*y/3, x, y, bottomRightRect);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Fix your slider listener to change the colors in the view (not your application class) and then call `invalidate`

   ```
   final RectAngle rectAngleView = (RectAngle) findViewById(R.id.rectangle);
   seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
           rectAngleView.topLeftRect.setColor(Color.rgb(23 - progress, 200 + progress, 99 + progress));
           rectAngleView.bottomLeftRect.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 133 + progress, 144 - progress));
           rectAngleView.topRightRect.setColor((Color.rgb(88 + progress, 200 - progress, 177 + progress)));
           rectAngleView.bottomRightRect.setColor(Color.rgb(230, 56 + progress, 233 - progress));
           rectAngleView.invalidate();
       }

       @Override
       public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

       }
   });
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also,  consider renaming `topLeftRect, bottomLeftRect, topRightRect, midRightRect, bottomRightRect` to `topLeftPaint, bottomLeftPaint, topRightPaint, midRightPaint, bottomRightPaint`.  Its kinda confusing since these fields aren't really rects (they are paints)

Comment: Thanks so much petey. I appreciate it. It worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wring here.

you forgot to grab a reference to your `RectAngle` (you can use `findViewById()`) and call `View.invalidate()` on it, after you set the new color. This will schedule a redraw of your `View` and `onDraw` will be called again. Here you can find the documentation for [invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()). 
As correctly pointed out by [@Petey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794088/petey), in onDraw you are resetting over and over the in the `Paint` objects

Comment: thanks Blackbelt. Is this how you say it?                                                 RectAngle rect;
rect = (RectAngle)findViewById(R.id.rectangle);
 rect.invalidate();                                                                                      I added it to the onProgressChanged method.

Comment: where did you put those lines?

Comment: stop hardcoding the colors in the `onDraw` method (example of hardcoding : `GlobalUIVariables.bottomLeftRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));`)

Comment: @petey: is it because of the hardcoding the colors? Blackbelt, I put it in OnProgreesChanged method in the main activity

Comment: yes it is. Remove every setColor/setStyle from onDraw

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I will modify it according to your comments and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks Blackbelt, then where do I set the initial colors for rectangles? In main activity?

Answer (score 1):

Did you added your custom Rectangle view to the activity_main layout?

If you haven't added that view, you should add it to the activity_main layout like this

```
<com.blah.blah.RectAngle
         android:id="@+id/rectangle_view"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Get handle to the RectAngle view and call invalidate on the RectAngle view to redraw on `onStopTrackingTouch`.

**Answer:**

In the Rectangle onDraw method it is using the colors you defined for the first time. Comment those or set them in the Rectangle view constructors or create method of the activity.

```
GlobalUIVariables.topLeftRect.setColor(Color.parseColor("#66FFFF"));
```

after commenting all these colors in the onDrawMethod, call invalidate method on the Rectangle in onProgressChanged like you are doing now.

Comment: Yes I did, I just added it to my post above.

Comment: did you added rectangle.invalidate() method `onStopTrackingTouch` ?

Comment: I added to onProgressChanged method. See the main activity class code above ( I just edited). Should I put it in onStopTrackingTouch?

Comment: Thanks krrish. I did as you said, but still nothing changed.